# ChartJs total of stacked bar

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm displaying a bar, with 2 stacked bars. My problem is that chartjs sum the total, and the heigh of the bar goes over total. Its there a way to make the height stops on "max" value of the stackeds bars?

bellow the example. the max value is 15, but the height on the chart goes on 25 (15 + 12 stacked)

[image: example]

Comment: I think you can set "max" option to the y axis. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#common-options-to-all-axes

Answer (score 1):

Resolved!

it was missing the following configuration:

scales: {
y: {
stacked: false
},
x: {
stacked: true
}
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).